# Why I'm getting this [UFW BLOCK] in my syslogs?

Tags: 12.04, log, ufw

I wonder why I get this error on my syslogs:

```
[7732763.396193] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=02:8b:1a:75:d5:7b:02:8b:1a:40:00:03:08:00 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=x.x.x.x LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53703 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35651 DPT=8443 WINDOW=457 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
```

I have just enabled the `ufw`. This error means that something going wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, it means that ufw blocked a connection from `SRC` to `DST` on TCP Port 8443.
Unless you **wanted** this connection to be successful it is not a bad thing.

Port 8443 is mainly used by webservices, for example it is used by VMware ESXi, or some (HTTPS) Application Servers.

You can check if your box is running anything on that port by issueing `sudo netstat -tulpen | grep 8443`

Comment: How can I stop this being put into `syslog` files?

Comment: @batman type `man ufw` into a terminal. Scroll down to `LOGGING`

Comment: You should be able to disable logging via `sudo ufw logging off`

Comment: Instead of disabling ufw logging completely, it is better to just [stop logging into syslog](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452125/redirect-ufw-logs-to-own-file)

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. Lots of different IP address trying what seem to be random ports. Their frequency is perhaps every second or so perhaps less. On another device and network I tried entering one of the `SRC` IP addresses in a browser and got `X.X.X.X refused to connect`. So I came to the conclusion these servers are reaching out but have blocked all incoming. Are these servers trying their luck randomly to gain access or collect information? ...my first experience of security concerns when managing a server. Glad I'd enabled `ufw`.

Comment: You can also stop logging it by whitelisting which IPs you want to allow connections, and then deny everything else as last rule, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1383632/1179344

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```sh
$ tail -1 /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
#& stop
```

This `#& stop` means that you are logging into `syslog`.

#### Teo, how can I stop it?

Well, you just need to run this command to stop logging into to the syslog:

```sh
sudo sed '/#& stop/s/^#//' -i /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

This command just uncomments the first match of the pattern `#& stop` in the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf`. In this case the last line, that is why we use `tail -1` to print the last line of the file.

Now verify it:

```sh
$ tail -1 /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
& stop
```

or just:

```sh
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```