# Redirect UFW logs to own file?

Tags: 14.04, log, ufw

Is there a way I can easily redirect the entries for UFW to their own log file at **/var/log/ufw** instead of filling up **/var/log/syslog** as it's becoming tricky to find solutions to problems with all this UFW stuff flying past me?

Answer (score 26):

In Ubuntu 15.10 and Debian Jessie there is a file /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf. It contains at the bottom `# & ~`. Remove the # in front of it to uncomment it and refresh rsyslog with the command `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` so that it takes in account the configuration change.

Comment: works for 14.04 too, and is simpler, just used `sudo service rsyslog restart` after changing it, thx!

Comment: This is what worked for me too (14.04). Simple is good.

Comment: In 18.04 the last line is `# & stop` but does the same when uncommented, rsyslog needs to be restarted indeed.

Answer (score 14):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 as well.  In my `/etc/rsyslog.d/` there's a file `20-ufw.conf` which has the following line:

`:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log`

What I've done is delete that file, and at the top of `50-default.conf` I added the following:

> :msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log 
>   & stop

Restart rsyslog with `sudo service rsyslog restart` and your UFW logs should be put into their own file and not into any other.

Comment: why not just edit `20-ufw.conf` and add the stop command there? In fact, it already has a template that can be uncommented, and it seems to work fine in my quick test.

Comment: @HRJ Personal preference?  The 20-ufw.conf file only has a few lines of text, most of which are comments.  I felt it wasn't necessary for its own config file.  Your suggestion accomplishes the same thing really - it's the `:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log` that needs to be modified/stopped.

Answer (score 6):

ufw uses rsyslog for logging to `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`:

To change the log file, edit `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and to the top add:

```
:msg, contains, "UFW" -/var/log/ufw.log
& ~
```

This will log all data that contains "UFW" to `/var/log/ufw.log` will prevent further processing of such data.

Comment: While ufw.log does now contain entries with your commands, syslog still receives messages.

Comment: Yes but syslog does report problems with your commands.

Comment: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, on or before line 1: invalid character '~' - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
Apr 21 15:58:41 markys-home-pc rsyslogd-2307: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]

Comment: I did copy and paste.  Same error.

Comment: The log has stopped accepting UFW commands on mass, however one or two are still sneaking through.  It's better now however the depreciation error still exists.

Comment: @markrich: Not sure why the bug is still there, most likely you are using rsyslog 7(since you are on 14.04) and the bug you talk about has been fixed in version 5: http://www.rsyslog.com/changelog-for-5-6-5-v5-stable/. Unsure what to do with the error message :/

Answer (score 6):

On 16.04 just comment out the last line in this file so that it reads

```
$ tail -1 /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf 
& stop
```

and restart rsyslog

```
$ sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
```

from now on, ufw logs will be in /var/log/ufw.log and not anymore in /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1):

I cannot post a comment yet with my reputation, hence posting a separate response.

chmike's answer still works for Ubuntu 20.04 (with a slight change). Basically

```
go to /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
Uncomment the last line: # & stop (i.e. delete #)
then restart rsyslog (i.e. /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart)
```

Comment: @David nevertheless, he/she can't comment yet.